# Magento2 how to set default columns in admin grid

Tags: grid, uicomponent, magento-2.2.5, column

You guys would be knowing that magento provides columns control in admin grid made using ui component. In that you can add all columns but only few can be displayed by default when grid load initially.

Here, I am showing same example with catalog product admin grid:

[image]

I have tried to find out reagrding how to implement this within my custom module admin grid. Unfortunately, I could not able to find it.

Can someone please let me know how we can define these default columns in admin grid? That would be really helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

magento provide facility to add product attribute directly in grid without any customization.

Please check carefully the selected checkbox are all table columns while unchecked are product attributes.

You can add any product or customer attribute in that section by below back-end configuration.

1. navigate to Stores and click on Product from Attributes section
2. click on any attribute you want to add in column section
3. go to **Advanced Attribute Properties** you will find configuration **Add to Column Options** just enable it and it will appear in grid selection section.

Please find attachment for your reference[image]