# Modifying user customer grid backend by default

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

We would like to modify the fields of the customer grid in the backend by default for all users. We know each user can change this themselves, but we need to implement this change for all users.

We have seen [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240006/magento2-how-to-set-default-columns-in-admin-grid?rq=1) question, but the question is about the product grid, which we don't need.

We would like to get rid of some of the columns and if possible order them.

Can we achieve this by modifying the DB or is there any backend configuration?

I have try:

```
  <column name="website_id" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Websites" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="110">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

And:

```
    <column name="website_id" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Websites" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="110">
        <settings>
            <filter>select</filter>
            <editor>
                <editorType>select</editorType>
            </editor>
            <dataType>select</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Web Site</label>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </column>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do using magento default dropdown feature. Also you can modify sortOrder in **customer_listing.xml**

Create a new module and added **app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml**
Copy columns from core module and modify sortorder. for example:

```
<columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
    <column name="name" sortOrder="30">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">Name</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
</columns>
```

Also you can added **<visible>false</visible>** like:

```
<column name="confirmation" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Confirmation" sortOrder="130">
    <settings>
        <dataType>select</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Confirmed email</label>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </settings>
</column>
```

After that remove record from **ui_bookmark** table which namespace **customer_listing**

Comment: I try with the website column and don't works... Only works if I set                     <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
 but i need see the column in the options columns. I update the question